# Как уcтановить фоновую картинку всему приложению?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Как уcтановить фоновую картинку всему приложению?
Нашел только вариант с Grid.Background, но картинка при таком раскладе закрывает только область а не весь экран.

Comment: Бекгрануд есть у многих элементов, не только у грида. В крайнем случае можно поставить картинку отдельным элементом и поиграться с Canvas.Left, .Top и .Zindex.

Comment: Canvas приму к сведению, но согласитесь - должно быть что-то стандартное =)

Comment: С Canvas тоже ничего не получается, верхняя полоса (где отображается время, уровень зарядки и сети) всеравно черная, + отступы по бокам и с низу.

Comment: у меня в эмуляторе сработал отрицательный маргин, но он вообще наглухо трей перекрыл, проще просто его отключить.